# OpenCL does not detect Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07) while on ArchLinux

Tags: c, opencl, intel, gpgpu, archlinux

I have recently installed ArchLinux, before that I was using Ubuntu. While on Ubuntu OpecCL was working. After installing the graphics driver for intel in Arch and OpenCL files and headers, I ran my previous wrote code for [addition of two number on OpenCL](https://github.com/Qazalbash/OpenCL/tree/main/AdditionOfNumber) but I was not working as the error shows there is no GPU device detected. My embeded GPU is,

```
>>> lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
```

Also in Ubuntu the OpenCL 3.0 was installed but here I only see OpenCL 2.1.

```
>>> clinfo
Number of platforms                               3
  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 LINUX
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns

  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 22.3.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   rusticl
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa/X.org
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 3.0 
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions with Version                cl_khr_icd                                                       0x400000 (1.0.0)
  Platform Numeric Version                        0xc00000 (3.0.0)
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA
  Platform Host timer resolution                  0ns

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 (Build 0)
  Driver Version                                  18.1.0.0920
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Max compute units                               8
  Max clock frequency                             1300MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     8
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
    Supported affinity domains                    (n/a)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Preferred work group size multiple (kernel)     128
  Max sub-groups per work group                   1
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 32      
    short                                                1 / 16      
    int                                                  1 / 8       
    long                                                 1 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8       
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              12335398912 (11.49GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           3083849728 (2.872GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   Yes
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           64 bytes
    Global                                        64 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    65536 (64KiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             65536 (64KiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144 (256KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            192740608 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   64 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          64 pixels
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
    Max number of read/write image args           480
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    32767
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                4294967295 (4GiB)
    Max size                                      4294967295 (4GiB)
  Max queues on device                            4294967295
  Max events on device                            4294967295
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    Sub-group independent forward progress        No
    IL version                                    SPIR-V_1.0
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                (n/a)
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint 

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

  Platform Name                                   rusticl
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [INTEL]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [INTEL]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.3.1
```

I have tried updating the graphics-driver for intel. I have installed the following packages,

```
>>> pacman -Qs opencl*
local/clinfo 3.0.21.02.21-1
    Simple OpenCL application that enumerates all available platform and device properties
local/intel-graphics-compiler 1:1.0.12812.4-1
    Intel Graphics Compiler for OpenCL
local/intel-opencl-clang 15.0.0-1
    Wrapper library around clang that can compile OpenCL C kernels to SPIR-V modules
local/intel-opencl-runtime 1:18.1.0.015-3
    OpenCL runtime for Intel Core and Xeon processors
local/intel-opencl-sdk 2020.1.395-2
    Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications
local/libclc 15.0.7-1
    Library requirements of the OpenCL C programming language
local/ocl-icd 2.3.1-1
    OpenCL ICD Bindings
local/opencl-headers 2:2022.09.30-1
    OpenCL (Open Computing Language) header files
local/opencl-mesa 22.3.3-3
    OpenCL support with clover and rusticl for mesa drivers
local/opencore-amr 0.1.6-1
```

And I also followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIVIHJmW1P0) from which I doesn't understand anything.

Comment: I would try uninstalling the other platforms (Clover and rusticl) as not all OpenCL programs handle multiple platforms well.

Comment: @SimonGoater This did not work.

Comment: What version of OpenCL does your program use? The program you linked to demands 3.0 #define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 300. Try changing it to 210.